# Can not install Plants vs. Zombies 2 on AsusFonetab

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have a AsusFonetab with Android 4.3 installed and 4GB free space but when I try to install [Plants vs. Zombies 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.game.pvz2_na) via Google Play, it says that the app is incompatible with my device.

How can I install this app?

[image: Can not install plan vs zombie 2 (req. 2.3++) on AsusFonetab (4.3)]

Answer (score 2):

Try [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.game.pvz2_row). Electronic Arts like to have one app for America and another for the rest of the world. If you click the 'Install' button it usually gives more information on why it is incompatible (e.g. "This item cannot be installed in your device's country").

[image]

Comment: I can't get PvZ 2 on a Google Edition S4, but fine on the Touchwiz version... So I'd say EA have a country restriction AND a White List of devices, cutting off any they forgot.

Comment: What does the message say when you click 'Install'? (see my screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

May be to do with the intel chipset - there are quite a few games that are unable to be installed on mine for that reason.

Comment: Didn't know this before, but can not confirm :(